# Conflicting rules in eclipse formatter, want to put braces on same line as method/class/etc, but don't want to join other line breaks

Tags: eclipse

I'm working on formatting our code base to more uniform coding conventions, and one of the changes is to require that opening braces be on the same line as the class, method, etc. This is easy to configure in eclipse, but I also want to set the formatter not to join already wrapped lines so that the formatter doesn't mangle custom line breaks. Unfortunately, this overrides the braces rule so old code that is formatted like

```
int foo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

is untouched by the formatter since fixing the brace would entail joining a line break. What's the best way around this? Do I need to find another formatter for our initial bulk format, and then we'll simply enforce policy on future commits?